# Locking table (or to use a transaction?) for payment

Tags: python, mysql

I have a web view similar to the following:

```
def process_payment(request, user):
    amount = 'SELECT amount FROM table where user=user'
    PayUser(user, amount)
    return 'OK
```

The problem with this is that if someone requested the same endpoint thousands of times (trying to cheat the system), it is possible that the `user.get_balance()` would return the same value and the user would get paid multiple times.

How could I set up a 'lock' to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to setup a lock in this instance. A way I have worked before is as follows: each worker thread that modifies the value has to set a worker GUID on the table row, then check whether the GUID is set to their GUID. Only then can they process it. No other worker can process the row until the GUID has been cleared and that is done only when process is completed. In workflow:

1. Get amount and see that user needs to be paid ensuring the worker GUID is null
2. Worker locks the row using a GUID
3. Worker checks GUID matches, if not, aborts
4. Worker updates the value and sets the GUID to null

You can also add a time_locked and then another process to reset GUID's to null if a row has been locked for longer than 10 minutes say. In this way, if a worker fails, it will correct itself.

Since the database is ACID compliant, this will work.

For generation of GUID look at uuid library.

Comment: That seems like a great idea. Would it be ok if I put the `payment_guid_lock` in the user table itself? Or does it need to go in a new table?

Comment: You can, or you can put it into the table with the amounts since this transaction concerns the amounts. Sorry, you don't lock the whole table, you just lock the row so you add a new column with the GUID.